# Changing Expandable ListView default icons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the default minimized and maximized icons for an expandable listview. I followed [this tutorial](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/af5369ce6071bf1e/bffe0fab687a53e0?show_docid=bffe0fab687a53e0)  closely, but I keep getting the following error in the **expander_group.xml** file:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/expander_ic_minimized.9').

The expander_group.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_expanded="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/expander_ic_maximized.9"/>
  <item
    android:icon="@android:drawable/expander_ic_minimized.9" />
 </selector>
```

As you can se in the above snippet, I have tried with both having a local copy of "expander_ic_maximized.9.png" in the res/drawable-hdpi folder and referencing the system icon but both scenarios yields the same error.

Hope someone can clarify the problem and help find a solution :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the ".9" parts? I don't think you need them EDIT: also should it been android:icon or android:drawable?

Comment: It helped.. Just needed to remove the .9 part of the filename. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Cool, I'll put the comment as an answer then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ".9" parts don't need to be put in the resource identifier :)

Answer (score 0):

In the res/drawable-hdpi folder, rename the folder to "expander_ic_maximized.png" instead of  "expander_ic_maximized.9.png"

Comment: No its the file that needs renaming :)